# failed to install laravel dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-dusk

Hi I use laravel 7 and I use wamp server and windows 10 as the os
I've successfully added laravel  dusk to the project by using

```
composer require --dev laravel/dusk
```

then I tried to install dusk scaffolding and chrome driver by running below command

```
php artisan dusk:install
```

then I've got below results

```
Dusk scaffolding installed successfully.
Downloading ChromeDriver binaries...

   ErrorException 

  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I am from Iran and Iran is in suspended countries and by using the VPN this problem solved for me